# How do I check if apache is using "compression" and "far-future" expiration dates?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, compression, deflate

How can I check and see if my web server is serving up content with compression and far future expires headers? YSlow is still telling me that I have resources that are being sent with plain text and without "far-future" expires headers even though I have added the following items to the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
</IfModule>
```

[image: Picture.png]

One of the things it says needs a expires header is a favicon.ico file, and here are the headers that are listed in Firebug:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2011 00:50:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Dec 2010 21:47:19 GMT
Etag: "f8233-47e-497f294aba7c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1150
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Sun, 18 Sep 2011 00:50:03 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/x-icon
```

One of the resources it says needs to be gzipped is the main index.php file, which is not sending headers of its own AFAIK. Here is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 18 Sep 2011 00:49:33 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=754163feea6fab8a8d6d7f0ef6ed3c29; path=/
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm trying to use `mod_deflate` since this is an Apache 2 server.

What am I doing wrong, what can I check, and how can I test further?

It's also telling me "There are 17 components with misconfigured ETags" - not sure what that means either. The e-tags are in the headers and they look OK to me.

Comment: YSlow is generally pretty accurate. You can also look at the response headers in Firebug or the network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: Yes, that's how I posted the headers above. However, it seemed like no matter what I changed in the config it didn't affect the YSlow report.

Answer (score 1):

For mod_deflate I recommend this [test](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http_compression/).